# owncloud with pre-existing user database

Tags: mysql, owncloud

I have a setup of dovecot with virtual users in a database. Now I would like to set up owncloud using the **same** users as already in the database. Is it somehow possible to configure owncloud as such one can log in only with the username and password from my existing database? Do you maybe know of a tutorial, that does that? (I couldn't find neither explanations on that nor a tutorial.)

The database has two columns, one with the user, one with the hashed password (sha512-crypt, with the normal format of mysql: $6$salt$hash )

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you can't use the external user database directly. However, it should be possible to use a [hook](http://doc.owncloud.org/server/6.0/developer_manual/app/appframework/hooks.html) that accesses the user database in a login attempt.

This post from the owncloud form shows how the hook `pre_login` is used. It checks for an LDAP group, but this should be easily adapted to your case.

Copy&paste of the essentials from the post:

Create a function that does the lookup in your database and returns `true` when the user is valid.

File `<owncloud>/apps/<your_plugin>/appinfo/hooks.php`

```
OC::$CLASSPATH['OC_Templates'] = 'lib/util.php';
class OC_user_ldap_Hooks{

public static function IsUserInGroup($parameters) {
            // replace this with your own database logic
            $filter = "(&(cn=owncloudusers)(memberUid=".$parameters['uid']."))";
           if(!OC_LDAP::searchGroups($filter, 'dn') && $parameters['uid']!="admin")
            {
                    $tmpl = new OC_Template( '', 'error', 'guest' );
                    $tmpl->assign('errors',array(1=>array('error'=>"User <b>".$parameters['uid']."</b> is not a member of a group allowed to login.")));
                    $tmpl->printPage();
                    exit;
            }
            return true;
    }
}
```

And in the file `<owncloud>/apps/<your_plugin>/appinfo/app.php`

```
OC::$CLASSPATH['OC_user_ldap_Hooks'] = 'apps/<your_plugin>/lib/hooks.php';
OCP\Util::connectHook('OC_User', 'pre_login', 'OC_user_ldap_Hooks', 'isUserInGroup')
```

This is just the basic to get you started, you will have to handle a little more (for example creation of a new user in ownCloud if a user logs in the first time).

Comment: thanks (: I already solved the problem by using the imap backend as I have a mail server accesing the same database anyway. But if I find the time to write the hook then I'll post my results here. (PS: sorry, I can't vote you up, still new here ^^ )